# Calculate number of days to holidays pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe consisting of a date column and a binary column named isHoliday, which simply consists of 1 if the date is a holiday and 1 if it is not. I want to create another two columns. One, a number of days to holiday column, which calculates the number of days left to the next holiday from both the date column and isHoliday column. Two, a number of days after holiday column, which calculates the number of days after to the last holiday from both the date column and isHoliday column.

Comment: can you provide a minimal example dataset in a reproducible format?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't share a reroducible example, here is a way (highly inspired by @[**`jezrael`**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) solution [**`here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66383638/19603419)) to calculate the numbers of days since/till the last/next holiday based on two columns `Date` and `isHoliday` in a dataframe composed of ten consecutives dates.

```
import pandas as pd

# --- CREATING A SIMPLE DATASET
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range("2022", periods=10), columns=['Date'])
df["isHoliday"] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

# --- CALCULATING THE TIME DELTAS
holidays = df['Date'].loc[df['isHoliday'] == 1].tolist()
holidays = pd.to_datetime(holidays, dayfirst=True)
df_hd = pd.DataFrame({'date1':holidays})

out = pd.merge_asof(df, df_hd, left_on='Date', right_on='date1', direction='forward')
out = pd.merge_asof(out, df_hd, left_on='Date', right_on='date1')

out['Days since the last holiday'] = out['Date'].sub(out.pop('date1_y')).dt.days
out['Days until the next holiday'] = out.pop('date1_x').sub(out['Date']).dt.days
```

##### `>>> display(out)`

[image]